# Getting the tcmid of the selected item on custom button click

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I have a custom button in the ribbon.

When i select any item (Component or Page) in tridion and click the custom button, i should be able to get the `tcmid` of the selected item.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var selectedID = selection.getItem(0);
```

in the _execute method, from my tutorial at http://www.curlette.com/?p=279

```
Extensions.WhoDidIt.prototype._execute = function WhoDidIt$_execute(selection, pipeline) {
```

Please spend some time (around 1 week) looking at existing examples and solutions, including my GUI Extension tutorials.  Please do make a strong effort and try for yourself before quickly posting here - you will learn more and have a greater understanding.

GUI Extension Samples:

- http://jaimesantosalcon.blogspot.com/
- http://tridionfanboy.wordpress.com/
- http://albertromkes.com/
- http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/
- http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/GUIextensionIn8steps.aspx
- http://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/linkedin.aspx
- http://www.curlette.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot robrtc.. The solution you have provided - worked.

Comment: If this solution worked, please click the Accept Answer button to the left of it. It signals to others that Robert's answer helped you solve your problem.